# Is it possible to use hibernation with secure boot, when using a swapfile on an encrypted root partition?

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, hibernate

I'm on Kubuntu 22.10. Given I'm installing onto a laptop with no S3 sleep support, having hibernate, secure boot, and an encrypted drive are 3 things that are pretty desirable. Is it at all possible to have all three at once? I've scoured the internet for quite a while, haven't found a difinitive yes/no answer or a solution if the answer is yes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to have encrypted swap on Ubuntu is to use LVM-on-LUKS.
a swap file on an encrypted root should work with an extra kernel parameter `resume_offset`.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file